# Why are some jars required in lib, and some aren't in a war?

Tags: spring, maven, jstl, war

I have a very basic Spring project, which uses JSTL and jsp for the views, and I started to receive a `404` error when I included a JSTL tag on the page. It worked fine without the tag.

[This](http://www.coderanch.com/t/605917/JSP/java/JSTL-core-Tomcat-giving-HTTP) post suggested to include the jstl jar in the WEB-INF\lib directory, which solved my issue, which makes some sense... however I'm left wondering *why* does only this jar need to be added to the lib directory? There are other dependencies that aren't required there.

All dependencies are managed by Maven.

Below is the project structure, showing all libraries used.

[image: project structure]

And pom.xml...

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>SpringClient</groupId>
<artifactId>Client</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Included because as a dependency of spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jstl/jstl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

As you can see, the jstl jar is now listed in two places, **why is this necessary?**

Comment: please post your pom.xml

Comment: If you have to put manually files into `WEB-INF/lib` than your a not managing your dependencies with Maven...

Comment: @Jaiwo99 thanks, have added pom

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your run-command from the webserver. Some add additional librarys by just adding it into a classpath argument, other webservers have special folders for that.
2. From my point of view, you should neber add libs directly into your project, when you use maven. Check http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/including-excluding-files-from-war.html or the http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html in general